# How to make PHP and PostgreSQL agree on how to calculate time intervals?

Tags: php, postgresql, datetime, time, compatibility

I have this PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT *, round(extract(epoch from ("last made" + "time span"::interval))) AS "next timestamp" FROM events ORDER BY "next timestamp" ASC NULLS LAST, "last made" DESC, "timestamp" DESC;
```

It returns a list of events with their "next timestamp" referring to the next time it will occur, based on the timestamptz column "last made", referring to when it last occurred, with the "time span" (such as "1 month" or "14 days", etc.) added to it.

I also have this PHP code:

```
function time_is_older_than($timestamp, $time_string)
{
    $d1 = new \DateTime($timestamp);
    $d1->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

    $d2 = new \DateTime();
    $d2->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    $d2->modify('-' . $time_string);

    if ($d1 < $d2)
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

Now, *most* of the time, this poses no problem. However, I have found two annoying cases right now where the PHP code thinks that the events have "expired" (already having occurred) but the PostgreSQL query's "next timestamp" is still in the future. They differ several days, or many hours, so it cannot simply be a timezone thing, which I first assumed before really diving into this annoying issue.

It should be noted that the PHP code took me a very long time to "accomplish", and countless rewrites, as I kept finding bugs in all my solutions prior to this. And now I found issues with this too!

Maybe it's "simply" a fundamental difference in how PHP and PG calculate such "time intervals"? Naturally, it goes without saying that I use the same string for PG and PHP; "1 month" for both, for example, rather than "1 month" for one and "30 days" for the other.

I found this note in the PHP manual:

> Note: Relative month values are calculated based on the length of months that they pass through. An example would be "+2 month 2011-11-30", which would produce "2012-01-30". This is due to November being 30 days in length, and December being 31 days in length, producing a total of 61 days.

I'm unable to find a similar explanation in the PG manual, but possibly this is related to my issue? If so, is there some way to make them both calculate this in the same manner, so that I don't get these annoying "false positives" when they disagree?

Also, please note that I often need to use the PHP function outside of this specific instance, so having an extra "boolean" column returned with the PG query saying whether it's in the future or not would not really solve my overall problem, except in this particular case. So please try to avoid that solution.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I can see is that it looks like you're using `setTimezone()` as opposed to specifying the timezone in the DateTime constructor, eg: `new DateTime('', new DateTimezone('UTC'));` which means that if your server's default timezone is anything other than UTC can cause problems such as the below:

```php
$string = "2021-04-01T12:00:00";
$utc = new DateTimezone('UTC');

$d1 = new DateTime($string);
$d2 = (clone $d1)->setTimezone($utc);
$d3 = new DateTime($string, $utc);

var_dump($d1, $d2, $d3);
```

Output:

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-01 12:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "Europe/Amsterdam"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-01 10:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-04-01 12:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
```

That said, how any given Date/Time library interprets relative formats like `now + 1 month` is fairly arbitrary and has no formal spec that I am aware of. [Would ISO8601 durations apply/work in this case?] Trying to make two such libraries agree with each other is going to be an exercise in futility. Your best bet is going to be picking one or the other and shifting all the logic into that. In this case I'd say that it's going to be Postgres.

Comment: Are you sure about the first thing? I mean, I can very well imagine that it matters when you set the timezone, but I assumed that they were identical? Why do they differ between doing it in the constructor and later?

Comment: Because unless it is specified in the date string or as a second constructor param the constructor implicitly uses the default timezone, and `setTimezone()` changes only the timezone, not the fixed point in time to which the already-created object refers.

Comment: Hmm! Will have to change that, then... Must admit I'm confused about the syntax you did use in your example, though. In particular the `(clone $d1)` part.

Comment: Objects are... "reference-y" in PHP and if you do `$d2 = $d1` both variables point at the same object. In order to make an actual copy you need to use `clone`. The parens are necessary to chain the method call off of it. Also worth mentioning, most DateTime method calls like `setTimezone()` both mutate the object state and return the object itself which tends to confuse some people into assuming that in `$d2 = $d1->setTimezone($tz);` yields a new DateTime object for `$d2` when it's two pointers to the same modified object.

Comment: Plenty of footguns here, but if you want to make extra sure you don't set any^H^H^H most of them off there's [`DateTimeImmutable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimeimmutable.php).